# build poco on OS X, fix8 cannot find poco

Tags: poco-libraries

I downloaded then built the latest poco library (a dependency to build/use fix8) with:

./configure 
make

then i try to build fix8 with:
./bootstrap
./configure
make
make install

however during the "./configure" i get the error below:

checking for Poco... no
ERROR: Poco development libraries are required. Install and try again (see wiki:prerequisites).

I've tried adding to the PATH but can't seem to get the build process to find poco.

any ideas on what i am missing to make poco findable by the fix8 build process?

Answer (score 2):

More explicitly ...

Install poco via: `brew install poco`

Assuming it is installed in /usr/local, run configure as: `./configure --with-poco=/usr/local`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have Poco sources and binaries. Looking at the [configure](https://github.com/fix8/fix8/blob/master/configure#L1583) script, it looks like

configure --with-poco=DIR

should work.